# Adding a web resource in Dashboard gives an "Refused to set unsafe header "Content-Length" error

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I am using MS CRM 2013 and trying just add a web resource with an Iframe. When I make that change and save in a dashboard, I get the error:

> Refused to set unsafe header "Content-Length.

Comment: It would help if you post your code.

Comment: If you are on Chrome it's normal

Comment: I ended up using a newer version of IE and it worked. There was no code. Just adding an IFrame in the Dashboard was resulting in this error.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a newer version of IE and it worked. There was no code. Just adding an IFrame in the Dashboard was resulting in this error.

I was working on Dynamics 2013 on-premise version.